# How would you use 気持ちを込める?

Tags: expressions

Could you please give me an example of the expression '気持ちを込める' and when you would use it?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[気持]{きもち}ちを[込]{こ}める is an often-used phrase when the mental or psychological aspect of something is being emphasized. = "to put my heart into ~~"

Baseball pitchers often say after a good performance, 「[今日]{きょう}は[一球一球]{いっきゅういっきゅう}気持ちを込めて[投]{な}げました。」 = "I put my heart and soul into every pitch I made today."

A singing teacher may say 「もっと気持ちを込めて[歌]{うた}いなさい！」 = "You need to put more heart into your singing!"

「気持ちを込めてこのケーキを[焼]{や}いた。」= "I put my feelings into baking this cake."

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer. Just a suggestion on your english examples: "I put my feelings into baking this cake." is unnatural. I suggest some alternatives: "I put my heart and soul into this cake."/"I put my heart and soul into baking this cake."/"I put everything I had into baking this cake."